# How to do validation from a viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a model with some validations below

```
        public class RequestABook
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name Required")]
            [DisplayName("Book Name")]
            public string BookName { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Zipcode Required")]
            [DisplayName("Zipcode")]
            public string ZipCode { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Contact Name Required")]
            [DisplayName("Contact Name")]
            public string ContactName { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Id Required")]
            [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Book Description Required")]
            public string BookDescription { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "You need to check one answer")]
            public string Answer { get; set; }
        }
```

I have a view model  here

```
        public class RequestViewModel
        {
            public RequestABook MyTestViewModel { get; set; }   
        }
```

I have my main page here that loads

```
        @model BookRequestValidation.Models.RequestViewModel

        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "RequestABook";
        }

        <h2>RequestABook</h2>

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Request Book</legend>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyTestViewModel.BookName)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyTestViewModel.BookName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MyTestViewModel.BookName)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyTestViewModel.ZipCode)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyTestViewModel.ZipCode)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MyTestViewModel.ZipCode)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyTestViewModel.ContactName)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyTestViewModel.ContactName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MyTestViewModel.ContactName)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyTestViewModel.Email)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyTestViewModel.Email)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MyTestViewModel.Email)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyTestViewModel.BookDescription)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyTestViewModel.BookDescription)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MyTestViewModel.BookDescription)
                </div>

                <div id="HCBudget" class="validation">
                    <label for="budgethealth">Budget Health</label>
                    @Html.RadioButton("Answer", "Red")
                    @Html.RadioButton("Answer", "Yellow")
                    @Html.RadioButton("Answer", "Green")  
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MyTestViewModel.Answer)   
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Request Book" />
            </fieldset> 
            }
```

Question: How do you guys handle validation with models used in a viewmodel.
Before I used this in a viewmodel everything was working well. By the time I used a viewmodel
validation stopped working.

Here is what the post action looks like.

```
        public ActionResult RequestABook()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RequestABook(RequestABook quote)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: The model in the view is `RequestViewModel` so the POST method must match `public ActionResult RequestABook(RequestViewModel quote)` (or use the `Prefix` property of `BindAttribute`). But this is not a view model. Its just a model that contains a property which is a data model and is bad practice (as is adding view specific attributes to data models). Refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc).

Comment: Thanks. I will read the link right away.

Answer (score 0):

It would help greatly if you posted your POST action. However, generally, I can say that validation is only run on related class instances if they are non-null. So, unless a value is posted for at least one of the properties on `MyTestViewModel`, it will not be instantiated by the modelbinder (`MyTestViewModel` will be `null`), and validation on its properties will not be run.

You can fix this scenario by always instantiating the `MyTestViewModel` property, either via the constructor of your view model or, probably better, using a custom getter and setter:

1. Constructor

   ```
   public class RequestViewModel
   {
       public RequestViewModel()
       {
           MyTestViewModel = new RequestABook();
       }

       ...
   }
   ```
2. Custom Getter and Setter

   ```
   private RequestABook myTestViewModel;
   public RequestABook MyTestViewModel
   {
       get
       {
           if (myTestViewModel == null)
           {
               myTestViewModel = new RequestABook();
           }
           return myTestViewModel;
       }
       set { myTestViewModel = value; }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks Chris. I posted the post action.